# Using cmake variable in execute_process command in cmake file

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, cross-platform

I am using `execute_process()` function in `cmake`.

```
message(" FLAGS = ${FLAGS}")
message(" SCATTERFILE = ${SCATTERFILE}")
set ( EXECUTE_COMMAND "arm-none-eabi-gcc ${FLAGS}  -E -P -x c-header ${SCATTERFILE} -o ~/ttt.ld" )
message("EXECUTE_COMMAND = ${EXECUTE_COMMAND}")
execute_process(COMMAND  ${EXECUTE_COMMAND} RESULT_VARIABLE rv )
```

Everything is displayed perfectly as a result of `message()` command, but it causes errors when it is run while parsing `cmake`. I think the `FLAGS` variable is not expanding as expected  while parsing. When I run the same `EXECUTE_COMMAND` which is displayed as a result of `message` command in the terminal it runs perfectly. what could be the issue ?

Edit:
I have removed `${FLAGS}` from

```
set ( EXECUTE_COMMAND "arm-none-eabi-gcc ${FLAGS}  -E -P -x c-header ${SCATTERFILE} -o ~/ttt.ld" )`
```

now I am using

```
set ( EXECUTE_COMMAND "arm-none-eabi-gcc   -E -P -x c-header ${SCATTERFILE} " )
```

The output is:

```
EXECUTE_COMMAND arm-none-eabi-gcc   -E -P -x c-header ~/scatterFile.scatter rv: No such File or directory.
```

If I simply enter this command on the terminal,

> arm-none-eabi-gcc   -E -P -x c-header ~/scatterFile.scatter

it executes and gives the expected results.

Comment: Who is reporting an error? CMake or the executed process? Please provide the output of your CMake run

Comment: the executed process

Comment: So please provide the relevant part of the CMake output (including the `MESSAGE` output and the error message)

Comment: The tilde is expanded by your shell.  It's not a valid filename for cmake.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to execute a program named "`arm-none-eabi-gcc -E -P -x c-header ~/scatterFile.scatter rv`". Notice the syntax of [`execute_process()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/execute_process.html):

```
COMMAND <cmd1> [args1...]
```

To make it even clearer, the documentatin could actually write it as:

```
COMMAND cmd1 [arg1 [arg1 ...]]
```

CMake expects the command name as one CMake argument and each command-line argument as another separate CMake argument. You're enclosing everything in quotes, however, which turns it into *one* CMake argument (containing lots of spaces). Change your code as follows:

```
set (EXECUTE_COMMAND arm-none-eabi-gcc ${FLAGS} -E -P -x c-header ${SCATTERFILE} -o ~/ttt.ld)

execute_process(COMMAND ${EXECUTE_COMMAND} RESULT_VARIABLE rv)
```

Comment: after removing the quotes it puts semicolions instead of white spaces
**arm-none-eabi-gcc;-E;-P;-x;c-header;~/scatterFile.scatter** which totally is useless

Comment: @theadnangondal Where do you observe the semicolons? In the `message()` output, or in the actual command line executed? Those are *very* different things.

Comment: **message()** output but there are also errors in the command line execution. Including **file not found** and **-x c-header has no effect after last file**

Comment: Might have to do with your content of `FLAGS`, hard to say without a [complete reproducing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you replace `arm-none-eabi-gcc` with a test script that will allow you to inspect the actual content of each command-line argument so that you can verify what you're passing in?

Comment: @theadnangondal Hm, weird. Can you edit the question to include the way you set `SCATTERFILE`, as well as the output of an argument-printing script like I suggested? Something like [this Python](http://ideone.com/tK0S2H).

Comment: I think that I can solve the problem from here. The argument printing script is a wonderful idea . thanks

Comment: @theadnangondal I always have one in my PATH. I find it's an essential thing when debugging complex shell commands, script-language program invocations etc.